# How to install a npm binary from a GitHub repo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to install a project with a binary through GitHub `yarn install global https://github.com ...`. The path for the binary is (package.json):

```
"bin": {
  "oatyp": "./build/cmd/oatyp.js"
},
```

On npm this makes a lot of sense since there are a couple of scripts that run before publishing:

```
"scripts": {
    "prepublish": "yarn build",
    "prebuild": "rimraf -rf build",
    "build": "tsc --project ./tsconfig.build.json",
    "test": "NODE_V8_COVERAGE=./coverage ava",
    "posttest": "c8 --all report -x example -x build -x node_modules --temp-directory=./coverage/ --report-dir=./coverage -r json"
  },
```

When installing through GitHub, however, this makes less sense since these "publishing" scripts are never invoked. As a consequence, I do not find the binary on my path after running the (global) install command.

I've tried creating a branch and commiting all the build artifacts to it but I still ended up without the binary.

**How do I install a binary package though GitHub that depends on build artifacts?**

Comment: You were on the right track with the git repo with the artifacts committed. Does that branch populate the `./node_modules/.bin/oatyp` file if you do a regular install (not global)?  Did you mean to do a `yarn global install ...`?

Comment: Hi Matt, no I don't see the binary in `./node_modules/.bin/oatyp` after running `yarn global add https://github.com/....`. But I see a console log after the install that says "package was installed with binaries".